# Firebase: action after read child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on project that sell **unique** soft products like serials or tickets. To be fast and reliable, we going to use **Firebase Real-time Database**.
The problem is I want to remove or update the sold ticket after the user get it.

One way to do so is using another server to do so manage the tickets and update the **Firebase** Database using **REST API**, but I want to do it with the **Firebase** only.

Another way to do it, after the user get a ticket, the client side app will sent a remove request. But I'm afraid of losing the data in the middle of this process. A user got a ticket but never removed from the database. As I said the ticket is **unique**.

How to do it with **Firebase** side only?

Comment: How does the user "get" the ticket ?

Comment: @user3210641 The tickets will stored in a Firebase database reference and a the user will read only one child of the tickets reference. But I have to remove it before another user request again.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for transactions, which combine a read and write operation. See this page in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you. Transactions what I need but still there is a problem: docs says `If another client writes to the location before your new value is successfully written, your update function is called again with the new current value, and the write is retried.` So it still readable by others! Is there something like **Serving queue**? If non, I think I will implement one myself.